# Custom UICollectionViewCell increases memory allocation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

After finishing my app, I realized that the memory allocation is incredibly huge.
I think I have isolated the problem to a view which makes use of a `UICollectionView`.
The collection view has custom `cell`.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 12;
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 MyCollectionCell *yearCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:myCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (yearCell ==  nil)
    yearCell = [[AgendaYearCollectionCell alloc] init];
yearCell.layer.shouldRasterize    = YES;
yearCell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
[yearCell setCurrentDate:newDate];

return yearCell;
```

}

I registered the nib of the custom cell in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UINib * nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"AgendaYearCollectionCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:myCellIdentifier];
```

`MyCollectionViewCell` is a custom (inherited) `UICollectionViewCell` and its `setCurrentDate` method does:

```
-(void)setCurrentDate:(NSDate *)date
{

    if (calendar == nil)
        calendar = [[myCalendarView alloc] initWithDate:currentMonth];

     [self.contentView addSubview:calendar];
      calendar = nil;
   [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

The problem is that memory increase linearly as I add/remove new cell to the view.
I was supposing that `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` does what I need: reuse cells keeping memory usage low.
But this does not happen. For instance, my collection view is a calendar: a grid of 12 months. Therefore, I need always 12 and only 12 cells.
There is a way for a better management of the collection ?

Comment: Are you using the same identifier when registering your nib and when dequeuing your collection view's cell?

Comment: Did you set cell identifier in xib file?

Comment: @Idindu: Yes, I mistake the code. Updated it.

Comment: @johnMa - not really. Where I have to set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I set my reuse cell identifier here[image]

**EDIT:**
I think here is your problem, you add calendar each time in collection view delegate,so you just reused your `MyCollectionCell` but your `calendar` in `MyCollectionCell` is not reused.that's why you can see the memory print grow. So , you should make `MyCalendarView` more reusable so that you don't have to alloc it each time.

```
-(void)setCurrentDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    if (calendar == nil){
        calendar = [[myCalendarView alloc] initWithDate:currentMonth];
        [self.contentView addSubview:calendar];
       // calendar = nil;//here you dealloc calendar which make `if(calendar == nil)` run each time.
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }

}// each calendar in Collection Cell won't be create or refresh again.
```

Comment: I did, but unfortunately the memory footprint does not change as I navigate the collection view.

Comment: I think you do something wrong in `-(void)setCurrentDate:(NSDate *)date` , see my edited answer.

Comment: So, if I got it, you suggest to delete calendar = nil?

Comment: Only delete that line will cause reusable cell won't refresh issue so that's not the solution, Since you only and always need 12 cells, you may consider not using the reusable cell technology. then you don't have to create calendar each time.

Comment: Another option is to remove the calendar from the list of subviews before creating a new one. (The leak is that it currently keeps adding more and more subviews, so just remove the old ones first.)

Comment: JohnMa, could please suggest another technology. I'll appreciate if you can post a minimal solution as answer...

Comment: Jesse, every cell has XIB and I add the calendar as its subview. I do not understand your solution,sorry.

Comment: However, I just deleted the line calendar = nil and the memory footprint stays steady!

Answer (score 0):

Don't init CollectionViewCell like UITabelView cell in cellForItemAtIndexPath. Delete all of these code

```
//    if (yearCell ==  nil)
//        yearCell = [[AgendaYearCollectionCell alloc] init];
//    yearCell.layer.shouldRasterize    = YES;
//    yearCell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Because your cell is Nib cell, bring all these setting into awakeFromNib in MyCollectionCell.m like this

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
[super awakeFromNib];
self.layer.shouldRasterize    = YES;
}
```

registerNib is enough in the case of Nib cell, remember specify your MyCollectionCell in Nib cell class.

Comment: I noticed that in Instruments most of the LIving objects are related to CoreAnimation (around 506 objects!)...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Instruments` for analysing your app's memory footprint. In `XCode` > `Product` > `Profile` and select `Leaks` on `Instruments`. It is very very useful to trace high memory usage responsible calls.